# Delete new lines in php string that start with a certain character

Tags: php, regex

I want to delete the lines in a php string that start with `>`

I tried exploding it into an array but it does not seems to work

```
$email = "This is the only text I want

> On Nov 19, 2017, at 10:58 PM, > wrote:
> 
> this is trash
>
";
$array = explode("\n",$email);
foreach($array as $arr) {
   if(!(preg_match(">",$arr))) {
    $output[] = $arr;
   }
}

$out = implode("\n",$output);
echo $out;
```

Comment: `I tried exploding it into an array but it does not seems to work` how does it _not seem to work_? What does it do?

Comment: there are no `\n` in your string so the explode isnt working

Comment: I see newlines when I paste it into a newline formatted file ;)  Totally depends though in reality. We have no idea where this string came from.

Comment: word up randall +1

Comment: You really should've read the documentation for `preg_match` more closely. `preg_match(">",$arr)` doesn't look anything like any of the examples in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$email = "This is the only text I want

> On Nov 19, 2017, at 10:58 PM, > wrote:
> 
> this is trash
>
";

$lines    = preg_split('/\R/', $email);
$filtered = [];
foreach($lines as $line)
    if(!preg_match('/^>/', $line))
        $filtered[] = $line;

$filtered = implode("\r\n", $filtered);
var_dump($filtered);
```

Output:

```
string(32) "This is the only text I want

"
```

Answer (score 1):

*Deleting* newlines could be done with

```
^(>.*)\R?
# start of line, >, anything afterwards, newline characters eventually
```

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php
$string = <<<DATA
This is the only text I want

> On Nov 19, 2017, at 10:58 PM, > wrote:
> 
> this is trash
>
DATA;

$regex = '~^(>.*)\R?~m';
$string = preg_replace($regex, "$1", $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

---

This yields

```
This is the only text I want

> On Nov 19, 2017, at 10:58 PM, > wrote:> > this is trash>
```

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2P6rgv/1/).

Comment: @chris85: Despite [these big glasses](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85) ;-) ?

Comment: They're just for distance apparently :(

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the logic behind your task, you wish to remove all "prior correspondence" in the email text which is indicated by lines starting with `>`.

Now, keep in mind, I have seen emails where people interlace old conversation text in their new text to respond in an itemized fashion.  Any attempts to remove prior convos in this type of situation will damage the intent of the message.  If that is not going to occur within the scope of your project, then we can move forward with a clean method:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8c032e1a047c63f4f4eef44be7b24c75cbbc82e))

```
$email = 'This is the only text I want

> On Nov 19, 2017, at 10:58 PM, > wrote:
> 
> this is trash
>
';

var_export(preg_replace('/\s*\R>.*/s','',$email,-1,$count));
echo "\n\nNumber of Replacements: $count";
```

Output:

```
'This is the only text I want'

Number of Replacements: 1
```

Not only does this method delete all prior conversation text in a single match/replacement, it goes a little further and trims the trailing space from the end of the current conversational text.  This is accomplished by matching zero or more white-space characters (`\s*`) before `\R` and permitting the dot (`.`) to match newline characters due to the `s` flag/modifier at the end of the  pattern.

You will notice if you remove the `s` flag from the pattern, then the number of replacements becomes `4` and the final newline character is not matched (because it isn't followed by a `>`.

If this was my project, this is exactly how I'd do it because you are left with a very clean result and with the fewest operations to get there.

p.s. For your implementation, just use: `preg_replace('/\s*\R>.*/s','',$email);`